# MVVM DataGrid with Summary Line

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've been working on getting a simple grid setup and I'm having issues getting a summary line either above or below the DataGrid. Is their some some way to get total counts in the datagrid for specifict columns?

Here is what I have:

```
<Window xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"  
        x:Class="TestWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test Window" Height="645" Width="900">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <DataGrid Height="500" ItemsSource="{Binding GridDetails}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Name" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path='Name', Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ID" Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path='ID', Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
                  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                     </Style>
                  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
               </DataGridTextColumn>
               <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NumClaims" Header="Claims" Binding="{Binding Path='NumClaims', Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">
                  <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                     </Style>
                  </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
               </DataGridTextColumn>
               <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NewClaims" Header="New Claims" Binding="{Binding Path='NumNewClaims', Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="80">
                  <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding NumNewClaims}"/>
                    </Style>
                 </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                   </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
             </DataGridTextColumn>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
   </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In the View Model

```cs
private ObservableCollection<GridDetail> _gridDetails;
public ObservableCollection<GridDetail> GridDetails
{
   get { return _gridDetails; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _gridDetails, value); }
}

private int _totalClaims;
public int TotalClaims
{
   get { return _totalClaims; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _totalClaims, value); }
}

private int _totalNewClaims;
public int TotalNewClaims
{
   get { return _totalNewClaims; }
   set { SetProperty(ref _totalNewClaims, value); }
}
```

The trouble I'm having is figuring out how to put the totals I've been tracking in the view model in the column header. This is my preferred method but I could also work with a summary row that is frozen to the top of the grid if that is simpler to implement.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a custom column header for each column. Then, bind the TextBlock with the property in the ViewModel. However, you need to play with the DataContext to make it work. Let's go by steps.

A custom header would be like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="NumClaims" Binding="{Binding Path='NumClaims', Mode=OneTime}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="100">

     <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
          <TextBlock Text="Claims" />
     </DataGridTextColumn.Header>

    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Now this would be the same as you have right now, but now you can add more things to the header, such as a `StackPanel`.

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Claims" />
        <TextBlock Text="35"/>  <!-- Dummy value -->
     </StackPanel>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

And if, as in your case, you would like to bind a property from your ViewModel, you would write

```
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Claims" />
        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext}" Text="{Binding TotalClaims, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
     </StackPanel>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

I hope that this helps.